# bluefish: quick bar not configurable and main menu invisible

Tags: 14.04, menu, bluefish

**Quickbar** is not allowed to configure. Just appears "..." and if I click on right button nothing happens. So it's not allowed **external filters/commands and outputs** resources because main menu is invisible.

I've got this output running it by user terminal:

```
(bluefish:3034): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.40.2/./gobject/gsignal.c:2462: signal 'expose-event' is invalid for instance '0xedf390' of type 'GtkWindow'
cleanup_scanner, memory scancache 0(0Kb+0Kb) found 0(0Kb) fcontext 0(0Kb) = 0Kb
```

When I've tried to access bluefish under **root terminal**, main menu appears and the **external filters/commands and outputs resources** are available but the **quickbar** remains not responding. console output:

```
error reading list 1 Erro ao abrir arquivo: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado

** (bluefish:3487): WARNING **: no configfile rcfile-2.0, try to convert config files from older versions

config file migration error 1:Erro ao abrir arquivo: Arquivo ou diretório não encontradoerror reading list 1 Erro ao abrir arquivo: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
cleanup_scanner, memory scancache 0(0Kb+0Kb) found 0(0Kb) fcontext 0(0Kb) = 0Kb
```

I'm under ubuntu 14.04 LTS and it's updated. My bluefish version is 2.2.5-1.

The problem was caused by bluefish, any ubuntu component, or both?